# Deploying project on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, deployment

I am new to AWS and I met a problem in deploying my project on AWS.

The circumstances is like:

I developed a website and this website has several domains like [www.xxxx.com](http://www.xxxx.com), user.xxxx.com, file.xxxx.com. I dont really register these domains. So during the development I modified my hosts file on my local desktop and used a Nginx to help me mapping these domain to other backend services.

```
    upstream uidevserver{
    server 127.0.0.1:8602 weight=10;
    } 

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  teacher.xxxx.cn;
        ssi on;
        ssi_silent_errors on;
        location / {
            proxy_pass   http://uidevserver;
        }

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://gatewayserver/;
        }     
   }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  ucenter.xxxx.cn;
        ssi on;
        ssi_silent_errors on;
        location / {
            alias   D:/project/xc-ui-pc-static-portal/ucenter/;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
        location /include {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        }
        location /img/ {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1/static/img/;
        }
        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://gatewayserver/;
        } 
    
   }
```

Now I am trying to deploy this website on aws, now the problem exists. Since I dont have these domain registered. I can only get a Elastic IP provided by Amazon. I can deploy a Nginx on the EC2 instance and map the ip to one of my domains but what about the others?

BTW, I dont want to use a NAT tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by creating a path base routing.

You can place your main website at `www.mywebsite.com` and then if you want to have `file.mywebsite.com` or `user.mywebsite.com`; you could create path base server block in your `nginx config` which will serve the website from:

`file.mywebsite.com --------> www.mywebsite.com/file`

`user.mywebsite.com --------> www.mywebsite.com/user`

This way it will serve your purpose with single IP.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I found that registring a public domain is not expensive on AWS route 53 and it can help me routing requests from my registered domain and sub domain to my EC2 instance which solved my probelm. However, thank you for your suggestions and wish you have a good day :)